# Created a custom widget but can't get it to pull the theme style?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, themes

So I'm new to making widgets. I've followed several tutorials and was finally able to make my very own custom widget (yay!). However, for some reason it is not pulling the theme styling?

I have tried with several themes and it is always the same. Every other widget I add pulls the theme styling for the sidebar, however my custom ones have no styling (except for the div styling I have placed into the coding).

Is there a specific code I need to add somewhere to force the widget to pull the theme style?

Sorry I just wanted to add - I am wanting to offer this widget to a few friends who run fansites, so I want it to automatically pull the style from any theme.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry didn't think to add that. Here is the code I am using:

```
            class Current_Projects extends WP_Widget
    {

      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct(
          'current-projects',
          'Current Projects',
          array(
            'description' => 'Current Projects'
          )
        );
      }

      public function widget( $args, $instance )
      {
        // output
        echo ' 
          <div style="padding:5px;margin:0auto;width:260px;text-align:left;margin-        right:10px;"><img width="25%" float="left"  src="'.esc_textarea($instance['image_uri']).'"         />
          <div style="float:right;width:65%"><div style="padding-top:0px;line-height:14px;        padding-right:10px;"><b>Project: </b>'.esc_textarea($instance['text']).'</div>
          <div style="padding-top:0px;line-height:14px;padding-right:10px;;"><b>Date:         </b>'.esc_textarea($instance['date']).'</div>
          <div style="padding-top:0px;line-height:14px;padding-right:10px;"><b>As:         </b>'.esc_textarea($instance['role']).'</div></div>
          <div style="padding-top:10px;        line-height:14px;">'.esc_textarea($instance['summary']).'</div>
          <div style="padding-top:10px;line-height:14px;"><a         href="'.esc_textarea($instance['imdb']).'">IMDB</a> &bull; <a         href="'.esc_textarea($instance['official']).'">Official Site</a> &bull; <a         href="'.esc_textarea($instance['gallery']).'">Gallery</a></div>


          <br /><br /></div>
                ';
      }

      public function form( $instance )
      {
        // new instances
        ?>
        <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Project Title</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['text']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('date'); ?>">Date</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('date'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('date'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['date']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('role'); ?>">Role</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('role'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('role'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['role']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('imdb'); ?>">IMDB URL</label><br />
          <input type="url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('imdb'); ?>" id="<?php echo         $this->get_field_id('imdb'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['imdb']; ?>" class="widefat"         />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('official'); ?>">Official Site         URL</label><br />
          <input type="url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('official'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('official'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['official']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('gallery'); ?>">Gallery URL</label><br />
          <input type="url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('gallery'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('gallery'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['gallery']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('summary'); ?>">Project         Summary</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('summary'); ?>" id="<?php         echo $this->get_field_id('summary'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['summary']; ?>"         class="widefat" />
        </p>
    <p>
          <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>">Image</label><br />
          <input type="text" class="img" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image_uri');         ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image_uri'); ?>" value="<?php echo         $instance['image_uri']; ?>" />
          <input type="button" class="select-img" value="Select Image" />
        </p>
        <?php
      }


    } 
    // end class

    // register
    add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return         register_widget("Current_Projects");') );

    // js
    function cp_enqueue()
    {
      wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
      wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
      wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      // script
      wp_enqueue_script('cp', '/wp-content/plugins/current-projects/script.js', null, null,         true);
    }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cp_enqueue');
```

Comment: We need to see the markup for the code that you're creating. there's before/after markup that is pretty standard that will ensure you're css will target the widget factory

Comment: Try using the classes, `widget`, `widget-container`, `widget-title`, and see if that finds you resolve.

Comment: No changes unfortunately! Thanks for the idea though, any others per chance? :)

Comment: If you have a widget that isn't getting the same styles as the default widgets, it's probably because it doesn't have the right classes. Check the classes of the elements in the widgets that _do_ work, and use them in your own widget.